# Express application crashes when it is built with webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, graphql

I am trying to use `graphql-upload` in a typescript express app (graphql api) built with webpack. When I run with ts-node my app works fine. But when I compile with webpack and then run I get a weird error when I try to upload a file.

#### My setup

- Typescript app
- Apollo server / Typegraphql
- Build with webpack

#### My Code

(stripped down to the essentials)

https://github.com/ziggy6792/graphql-file-uploads

#### My Problem

When I run with ts-node `yarn start:ts:node` then run `yarn test` an image gets uploaded no problem

But then I build with webpack `yarn start` then run `yarn test` I get the following error

```
/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:56105
            if (!isObject(operations) && !Array.isArray(operations))
                 ^

TypeError: isObject is not a function
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:56105:18)
    at Busboy.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at Busboy.module.exports../node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js.Busboy.emit (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:32204:33)
    at PartStream.onEnd (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:32528:15)
    at PartStream.emit (node:events:390:22)
    at Dicer.onPart (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:32386:13)
    at Dicer.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at Dicer.module.exports../node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js.Dicer.emit (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:45439:35)
    at Dicer.module.exports../node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js.Dicer._oninfo (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:45540:12)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:45486:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

#### My Attempts to solve

I am not sure if this actually a problem with `graphql-upload` or `webpack` or something else. I also noticed that my issue looks similar to this [issue](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/issues/218), but I didn't really understand if there were any fixes to that issue and if indeed it is the same issue I am facing.

I tried to upgrade webpack (branch `upgraded-packages`) but this made the problem worse as I get this issue when I start the server

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'graphql' of undefined
    at getPeerDependencyGraphQLRequirement (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:104216:44)
    at Object.ensureInstalledCorrectGraphQLPackage (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:104221:32)
    at Function.checkForErrors (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:103346:27)
    at Function.generateFromMetadataSync (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:103325:14)
    at Function.generateFromMetadata (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:103315:29)
    at Object.buildSchema (/Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:103940:61)
    at /Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:99831:41
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/sive/Documents/workspace/graphql-file-uploads/dist/index.js:99819:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are bundling a server side application? Do you want to run in a serverless environment? Webpack is usually used for creating browser bundles. Getting it to work for node might require some special configuration.

Answer (score 1):

### My best guess at the problem

From reading the linked issue it seems like `isObject` seems to ship ECMA Script modules with a newer version. Webpack might pick the ES modules version, but this version differs in the sense that the default export is now `default` and Apollo Server would have to import it as such or call `isObject.default`. In [this changelog](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/isobject/releases/tag/4.0.0) they say it might be breaking for users using bundlers.

### Your two options now:

You could [use yarn force the dependency to a previous version](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/#toc-how-to-use-it) of `isobject`:

```
{
  ...
  "resolutions": {
    "graphql-file-uploads/isobject": "3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Or you could simply not bundle your app and use TypeScript for building instead. You lose the benefits of bundling, but you are using an environment that is much more common for running node apps. Furthermore you will use TypeScript as a compiler just like `ts-node` unifying your development and production tooling.

You can compile using TypeScript like this:

```
yarn tsc 'src/**/*.ts'
```

In your TSConfig you should configure the output so that it also emits files to `/dist`.